# Producing a file whose content is the concatenation of the copies of the contents of f1 and f2

Tags: java, file, concatenation

How can I modify the method of annale2013q3 to convert it into a method that allows from 2 files f1 and f2 to produce a third file whose content is the concatenation of the copies of the contents of f1 and f2 (in that order)?

At the moment I only have enough code to copy one file to another:

```
public class annale2013q3{

    public static void (File file,OutputStream os) throws {
        BufferInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte b ;
        do {
        b = bis.read( );
        if (b!= -1 ) os.write(b);
        }
        while (b!=-1);
        bis.close( );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue? I'm not sure I see a problem

Comment: Write another method that calls your existing method twice: once for each file. By the way, your existing method does the same thing as one that already exists in the Java API: [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: _How can I modify the method of question 3_ Is this the signature of the method of question 3: `public static void (File file,OutputStream os)` ? Or is this your changed method?

Comment: @Abra I meant annale2013q3 sorry ! I named the class with my number of attempt

Comment: @JClassic the problem is that I have achieved to read and write from a file into another but I don't know how to read several and merge them

Comment: You can append to files @ThePassenger

Comment: If `Files.copy` (as DodgyCodeException mentions) won't do it for you, you should at least read/write a `byte[]` buffer, not a single byte at a time; and using a `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` may be more efficient. Or at a *nix command prompt: `$ cat f1 f2 > f3`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a collection of files to the method and iterate through them. You should also be a bit more careful about closing the files you open in the method. You can use the try-with-resource syntax to ensure the input streams are closed.

```
    public static void concat(Collection<File> files, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        for (File file : files) {
            try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
                int b;
                while ((b = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    os.write(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```